# ¿Alguna alternativa o una orientación para solucionar mi problema?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estimados, estoy retomando nuevamente en la programación, la cual me topé con este problema:
Lo que sucede es que en la referencia actualicé el Bootstrap, luego al ejecutar mi código me dice error de referencia la cual he buscado toda la solución posible sin obtener resultado.
Me fijé en la linea 40, luego quité 39,40,41 me visualiza pero del view de Bootstrap y no de mi Index del proyecto.
¿Qué debería de hacer?.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las imágenes con código no son muy bien recibidas en la comunidad. Si alguien desea probar tu código y buscar los errores o continuar una solución le obligas a programar todo desde cero. Te sugiero que copies tu código y lo pegues en tu pregunta una vez editada como texto. Un saludo

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.